# update increment of serial field from several records in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, increment

I want to change the increment value of all my columns that use sequencial IDs. How can I do it?

I tried the following 2 approaches, both failed:

```
UPDATE information_schema.sequences SET increment=1;
```

This doesn't work because information_schema.sequences it's a view.

I also tried to use ALTER SEQUENCE, adding a FROM at the end, like:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE A.sequence_name INCREMENT BY 2 FROM (SELECT * FROM information_schema.sequences) AS A
```

But I get a syntax error.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `setval` from [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html)

OR

`ALTER SEQUENCE... RESTART WITH...` as described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html)

**EDITED TWICE**

Sample how to change all sequences in owned schema:

```
do
$$
declare
i record;
begin
for i in (select * from information_schema.sequences) loop
execute $e$ALTER SEQUENCE $e$||i.sequence_name||$e$ INCREMENT BY 2$e$;
end loop;
end;
$$
;
DO
```

Comment: setval doens't change the increment, only the current value... ALTER SEQUENCE doesn't accept values from a SELECT...

Comment: sorry, I edited my question in order to be more clear.

Comment: yes, change the step or increment of all my IDs generated incrementally.

Comment: ah for all! that's why you select it from view. well then you need a do block

Comment: @alface this sample should do the job